# Adding and Removing UIBarButtonItems to UINavigationBar from Multiple Views

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, mainwindow

I currently have a Main Window set up as a UINavigationController (also is the root view controller), and I have two views.  The first view is the login screen, and the second screen is a table view screen.  What I would like to have happen is to show different UIBarButtonItems based on what screen is showing up.  For instance, when the logon screen is being displayed, I want a left button on the navigation bar to be displayed (more specifically, it'd be a Settings button before logging in).  Once the user logs in, I want the left button to say "Logout" and the right to be a reload button.  I've tried programmatically adding the buttons, but they won't show up.  Any suggestions?

Also, I've gotten most of this done in IB, but I feel like it would probably be easier to add these buttons programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All subclasses of `UIViewController` have a property called [`navigationItem`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/navigationItem). While it is readonly, you can alter its [properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006933-CH3-DontLinkElementID_3). So in `LoginViewController`, you would do `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = /* Code to create the bar button */` and likewise within the `TableViewController`. Let me know if you need more detail.

Comment: I see, I think I'll stick with this approach.  I did read up on this but it wasn't working out for me.  Thanks!